# Boot menu Problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

I'm new to ubuntu.

I have installed ubuntu with windows 10 successfully.After reboot I have to log to ubuntu by goto boot options and choose.

First time there was a 3 options.

After reboot there was a 5 options and its repeat after after again again.

I have a photo to show.but i cant upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands at the terminal command line of:
sudo apt-get -qq update; sudo apt-get -qq -y upgrade; sudo apt-get -qq -y autoremove

Then try:

sudo install-grub  [/dev/sda, or other device path]
sudo grub-update

if missing, then sudo apt-get install  will install it for you.

install-grub allows you to specify a target drive for the grub2 install.  Normally this would just be /dev/sda, meaning your first internal hard drive/  It overwrites the MBR, or Master Boot Record.  But there are occasions where you want the boot to go to a different drive, like a USB HDD.  People put grub2 on DVDs, CDs, floppies, or USB drives.  They have to plug in the particular booy means to get into the Linux system.  Otherwise, the sysrem boots from the first hard drive it can find with a boot process in the MBR.

A couple of links that go into the process in more detail:
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Note: It's not that tricky, really.  Reinstalling and updating grub gets rid of the spill over, and alsi makes your present boot partition the first primary choice.  The links above really serve to help you better understand the process, and deal with certain issues that people might face in a situation like this.